# AJAX Page Loading and Progress

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress, jquery

I want to make a jQuery AJAX page load with a progress bar at the top. I have found an example of what I am trying to achieve [here](http://www.barrelny.com/).

I could use a pointer on where to start.

I intend on using it in a WordPress site.

Comment: i don't use jquery but if u want i have an xhr2 example that will do the job in a native way.. the point is that not all browsers support that...but almost all latest do.http://caniuse.com/xhr2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this reference page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest). Specify a callback for `onreadystatechange`. A simple loading bar would just increment the bar a little bit as the `readyState` changes. This might be what the linked site does, and this is what modern browsers do (they switch the loading icon once the headers are received or once a connection is made). A more complex loading bar would read the headers received from the request when `HEADERS_RECEIVED`, then compare the content-length header (when `LOADING`) to the number of bytes received so far:

> Downloading; responseText holds partial data.

This technique might be too much trouble to for the value added. AJAX is typically designed to return light-weight data so loading time shouldn't be long enough to really need a fine-grained loading bar.

You might have to implement this differently if using jQuery, but the algorithm is the same.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look into this. I will reconsider the need for a loading bar, at first I thought it would be quite cool but maybe more trouble than it's worth.